# Не работает css для Retina-дисплеев

Tags: css, css3, шрифты, media-queries

Всем привет, у меня такая проблема я хочу использовать font-weight: 100 только для Retina-дисплее, а font-weight: 300 для обычных мониторов. Но почему-то браузер просто игнорирует @media перечеркивая его значение и вставляя font-weight: 300. (Использую макбук для проверки)

That's my CSS:

```
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
a {
    font-weight: 100;
}
}
a {
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
a {
    font-weight: 300;
}
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
   a {
       font-weight: 100;
   }
}
```

P. S.: сначала должны идти общие стили, а уже после частные. По этому font-weight: 300 (в вашем коде) имеет больший приоритет